# Could someone explain how the all() function work in this scenario

Tags: python

```
list2 = [“apples”,”pear”,”cookie”]
list1 = [“apples”,”pear”,”cookie”, “popcorn”, “candy”]
Check = all(item in list1 for item in list2)

If Check:
   print(“items in list2 is also in list1”)
```

Im confused on how exactly the `all(item in list1 for item in list2)` works and i was wondering if someone could explain the process taking place

Comment: Ps I couldnt find the off topic tag

Comment: simultaneous check of all conditions

Comment: @cards that is incorrect. It does not check all conditions, and certainly it does not do it simultaneously.

Comment: `all` return `True` if all statements are __simultenously__ `True`. If a `False` is met then return `False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent form of `all` in Python:

```
def all(iterable):
    for val in iterable:
        if not val:
            return False
    return True
```

Because you are passing a generator, it will yield the value of `item in list1` for each item in `list2` one by one, so it is iterable.